# TLS Configuration OpenSIPS

Tags: sip, tls1.2, opensips

I'm trying to configure my OpenSIPS server to allow TLS encrypted communications.

At first, I'm trying with the build-in certificates that OpenSIPS provide.
What I've done until now is generating a new Residential Script (opensips_residential.cfg) in which ENABLE_TCP & ENABLE_TLS have been enabled. 
Now I have two configuration files, opensips.cfg with the follow lines:

```
#
# $Id$
#
# OpenSIPS residential configuration script
#     by OpenSIPS Solutions <team@opensips-solutions.com>
#
# This script was generated via "make menuconfig", from
#   the "Residential" scenario.
# You can enable / disable more features / functionalities by
#   re-generating the scenario with different options.#
#
# Please refer to the Core CookBook at:
#      http://www.opensips.org/Resources/DocsCookbooks
# for a explanation of possible statements, functions and parameters.
#


####### Global Parameters #########

log_level=3
log_stderror=no
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0

children=4

/* uncomment the following line to enable debugging */
#debug_mode=yes

/* uncomment the next line to enable the auto temporary blacklisting of 
   not available destinations (default disabled) */
#disable_dns_blacklist=no

/* uncomment the next line to enable IPv6 lookup after IPv4 dns 
   lookup failures (default disabled) */
#dns_try_ipv6=yes

/* comment the next line to enable the auto discovery of local aliases
   based on revers DNS on IPs */
auto_aliases=no


listen=udp:192.168.1.57:5060   # CUSTOMIZE ME

####### Modules Section ########

#set module path
mpath="/usr/local//lib64/opensips/modules/"

#### SIGNALING module
loadmodule "signaling.so"

#### StateLess module
loadmodule "sl.so"

#### Transaction Module
loadmodule "tm.so"
modparam("tm", "fr_timeout", 5)
modparam("tm", "fr_inv_timeout", 30)
modparam("tm", "restart_fr_on_each_reply", 0)
modparam("tm", "onreply_avp_mode", 1)

#### Record Route Module
loadmodule "rr.so"
/* do not append from tag to the RR (no need for this script) */
modparam("rr", "append_fromtag", 0)

#### MAX ForWarD module
loadmodule "maxfwd.so"

#### SIP MSG OPerationS module
loadmodule "sipmsgops.so"

#### FIFO Management Interface
loadmodule "mi_fifo.so"
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_name", "/tmp/opensips_fifo")
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_mode", 0666)


#### URI module
loadmodule "uri.so"
modparam("uri", "use_uri_table", 0)

#### USeR LOCation module
loadmodule "usrloc.so"
modparam("usrloc", "nat_bflag", "NAT")
modparam("usrloc", "db_mode",   0)

#### REGISTRAR module
loadmodule "registrar.so"

/* uncomment the next line not to allow more than 10 contacts per AOR */
#modparam("registrar", "max_contacts", 10)

#### ACCounting module
loadmodule "acc.so"
/* what special events should be accounted ? */
modparam("acc", "early_media", 0)
modparam("acc", "report_cancels", 0)
/* by default we do not adjust the direct of the sequential requests.
   if you enable this parameter, be sure the enable "append_fromtag"
   in "rr" module */
modparam("acc", "detect_direction", 0)


#### UDP protocol
loadmodule "proto_udp.so"

####### Routing Logic ########

# main request routing logic

route{
    if (!mf_process_maxfwd_header("10")) {
        sl_send_reply("483","Too Many Hops");
        exit;
    }

    if (has_totag()) {
        # sequential requests within a dialog should
        # take the path determined by record-routing
        if (loose_route()) {

            if (is_method("BYE")) {
                # do accunting, even if the transaction fails
                do_accounting("log","failed");
            } else if (is_method("INVITE")) {
                # even if in most of the cases is useless, do RR for
                # re-INVITEs alos, as some buggy clients do change route set
                # during the dialog.
                record_route();
            }

            # route it out to whatever destination was set by loose_route()
            # in $du (destination URI).
            route(relay);
        } else {

            if ( is_method("ACK") ) {
                if ( t_check_trans() ) {
                    # non loose-route, but stateful ACK; must be an ACK after 
                    # a 487 or e.g. 404 from upstream server
                    t_relay();
                    exit;
                } else {
                    # ACK without matching transaction ->
                    # ignore and discard
                    exit;
                }
            }
            sl_send_reply("404","Not here");
        }
        exit;
    }

    # CANCEL processing
    if (is_method("CANCEL"))
    {
        if (t_check_trans())
            t_relay();
        exit;
    }

    t_check_trans();

    if ( !(is_method("REGISTER")  ) ) {
        if (from_uri==myself)
        {
        } else {
            # if caller is not local, then called number must be local
            if (!uri==myself) {
                send_reply("403","Rely forbidden");
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    # preloaded route checking
    if (loose_route()) {
        xlog("L_ERR",
        "Attempt to route with preloaded Route's [$fu/$tu/$ru/$ci]");
        if (!is_method("ACK"))
            sl_send_reply("403","Preload Route denied");
        exit;
    }

    # record routing
    if (!is_method("REGISTER|MESSAGE"))
        record_route();

    # account only INVITEs
    if (is_method("INVITE")) {
        do_accounting("log");
    }

    if (!uri==myself) {
        append_hf("P-hint: outbound\r\n"); 
        route(relay);
    }

    # requests for my domain
    if (is_method("PUBLISH|SUBSCRIBE"))
    {
        sl_send_reply("503", "Service Unavailable");
        exit;
    }

    if (is_method("REGISTER"))
    {
        if (!save("location"))
            sl_reply_error();

        exit;
    }

    if ($rU==NULL) {
        # request with no Username in RURI
        sl_send_reply("484","Address Incomplete");
        exit;
    }

    # do lookup with method filtering
    if (!lookup("location","m")) {
        t_newtran();
        t_reply("404", "Not Found");
        exit;
    } 

    # when routing via usrloc, log the missed calls also
    do_accounting("log","missed");
    route(relay);
}


route[relay] {
    # for INVITEs enable some additional helper routes
    if (is_method("INVITE")) {
        t_on_branch("per_branch_ops");
        t_on_reply("handle_nat");
        t_on_failure("missed_call");
    }

    if (!t_relay()) {
        send_reply("500","Internal Error");
    };
    exit;
}




branch_route[per_branch_ops] {
    xlog("new branch at $ru\n");
}


onreply_route[handle_nat] {

    xlog("incoming reply\n");
}


failure_route[missed_call] {
    if (t_was_cancelled()) {
        exit;
    }

    # uncomment the following lines if you want to block client 
    # redirect based on 3xx replies.
    ##if (t_check_status("3[0-9][0-9]")) {
    ##t_reply("404","Not found");
    ##  exit;
    ##}

}
```

And the other configuration file is the one that I generated with menuconfig tool:

```
#
# OpenSIPS residential configuration script
#     by OpenSIPS Solutions <team@opensips-solutions.com>
#
# This script was generated via "make menuconfig", from
#   the "Residential" scenario.
# You can enable / disable more features / functionalities by
#   re-generating the scenario with different options.#
#
# Please refer to the Core CookBook at:
#      http://www.opensips.org/Resources/DocsCookbooks
# for a explanation of possible statements, functions and parameters.
#


####### Global Parameters #########

log_level=3
log_stderror=no
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0

children=4

/* uncomment the following lines to enable debugging */
#debug_mode=yes

/* uncomment the next line to enable the auto temporary blacklisting of 
   not available destinations (default disabled) */
#disable_dns_blacklist=no

/* uncomment the next line to enable IPv6 lookup after IPv4 dns 
   lookup failures (default disabled) */
#dns_try_ipv6=yes

/* comment the next line to enable the auto discovery of local aliases
   based on revers DNS on IPs */
auto_aliases=no


listen=udp:192.168.1.57:5060   # CUSTOMIZE ME

listen=tcp:192.168.1.57:5060   # CUSTOMIZE ME 
listen=tls:192.168.1.57:5061   # CUSTOMIZE ME 

####### Modules Section ########

#set module path
mpath="/usr/local/lib/opensips/modules/"

#### SIGNALING module
loadmodule "signaling.so"

#### StateLess module
loadmodule "sl.so"

#### Transaction Module
loadmodule "tm.so"
modparam("tm", "fr_timeout", 5)
modparam("tm", "fr_inv_timeout", 30)
modparam("tm", "restart_fr_on_each_reply", 0)
modparam("tm", "onreply_avp_mode", 1)

#### Record Route Module
loadmodule "rr.so"
/* do not append from tag to the RR (no need for this script) */
modparam("rr", "append_fromtag", 0)

#### MAX ForWarD module
loadmodule "maxfwd.so"

#### SIP MSG OPerationS module
loadmodule "sipmsgops.so"

#### FIFO Management Interface
loadmodule "mi_fifo.so"
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_name", "/tmp/opensips_fifo")
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_mode", 0666)


#### URI module
loadmodule "uri.so"
modparam("uri", "use_uri_table", 0)











#### USeR LOCation module
loadmodule "usrloc.so"
modparam("usrloc", "nat_bflag", "NAT")
modparam("usrloc", "db_mode",   0)

#### REGISTRAR module
loadmodule "registrar.so"
modparam("registrar", "tcp_persistent_flag", "TCP_PERSISTENT")

/* uncomment the next line not to allow more than 10 contacts per AOR */
#modparam("registrar", "max_contacts", 10)

#### ACCounting module
loadmodule "acc.so"
/* what special events should be accounted ? */
modparam("acc", "early_media", 0)
modparam("acc", "report_cancels", 0)
/* by default we do not adjust the direct of the sequential requests.
   if you enable this parameter, be sure the enable "append_fromtag"
   in "rr" module */
modparam("acc", "detect_direction", 0)




















loadmodule "proto_udp.so"

loadmodule "proto_tcp.so" 
loadmodule "proto_tls.so"
modparam("proto_tls","verify_cert", "1")
modparam("proto_tls","require_cert", "0")
modparam("proto_tls","tls_method", "TLSv1")
modparam("proto_tls","certificate", "/usr/local/etc/opensips/tls/user/user-cert.pem")
modparam("proto_tls","private_key", "/usr/local/etc/opensips/tls/user/user-privkey.pem")
modparam("proto_tls","ca_list", "/usr/local/etc/opensips/tls/user/user-calist.pem")



####### Routing Logic ########

# main request routing logic

route{


    if (!mf_process_maxfwd_header("10")) {
        sl_send_reply("483","Too Many Hops");
        exit;
    }

    if (has_totag()) {
        # sequential request withing a dialog should
        # take the path determined by record-routing
        if (loose_route()) {

            if (is_method("BYE")) {
                # do accounting even if the transaction fails
                do_accounting("log","failed");
            } else if (is_method("INVITE")) {
                # even if in most of the cases is useless, do RR for
                # re-INVITEs alos, as some buggy clients do change route set
                # during the dialog.
                record_route();
            }



            # route it out to whatever destination was set by loose_route()
            # in $du (destination URI).
            route(relay);
        } else {

            if ( is_method("ACK") ) {
                if ( t_check_trans() ) {
                    # non loose-route, but stateful ACK; must be an ACK after 
                    # a 487 or e.g. 404 from upstream server
                    t_relay();
                    exit;
                } else {
                    # ACK without matching transaction ->
                    # ignore and discard
                    exit;
                }
            }
            sl_send_reply("404","Not here");
        }
        exit;
    }

    # CANCEL processing
    if (is_method("CANCEL"))
    {
        if (t_check_trans())
            t_relay();
        exit;
    }

    t_check_trans();

    if ( !(is_method("REGISTER")  ) ) {

        if (from_uri==myself)

        {

        } else {
            # if caller is not local, then called number must be local

            if (!uri==myself) {
                send_reply("403","Rely forbidden");
                exit;
            }
        }

    }

    # preloaded route checking
    if (loose_route()) {
        xlog("L_ERR",
        "Attempt to route with preloaded Route's [$fu/$tu/$ru/$ci]");
        if (!is_method("ACK"))
            sl_send_reply("403","Preload Route denied");
        exit;
    }

    # record routing
    if (!is_method("REGISTER|MESSAGE"))
        record_route();

    # account only INVITEs
    if (is_method("INVITE")) {

        do_accounting("log");
    }


    if (!uri==myself) {
        append_hf("P-hint: outbound\r\n"); 

        # if you have some interdomain connections via TLS
        ## CUSTOMIZE IF NEEDED
        ##if ($rd=="tls_domain1.net"
        ## || $rd=="tls_domain2.net"
        ##) {
        ##  force_send_socket(tls:127.0.0.1:5061); # CUSTOMIZE
        ##}

        route(relay);
    }

    # requests for my domain

    if (is_method("PUBLISH|SUBSCRIBE"))
    {
        sl_send_reply("503", "Service Unavailable");
        exit;
    }

    if (is_method("REGISTER"))
    {


        if ( proto==TCP || proto==TLS || 0 ) setflag(TCP_PERSISTENT);



        if (!save("location"))
            sl_reply_error();

        exit;
    }

    if ($rU==NULL) {
        # request with no Username in RURI
        sl_send_reply("484","Address Incomplete");
        exit;
    }







    # do lookup with method filtering
    if (!lookup("location","m")) {


        t_newtran();
        t_reply("404", "Not Found");
        exit;
    } 



    # when routing via usrloc, log the missed calls also
    do_accounting("log","missed");
    route(relay);
}


route[relay] {
    # for INVITEs enable some additional helper routes
    if (is_method("INVITE")) {



        t_on_branch("per_branch_ops");
        t_on_reply("handle_nat");
        t_on_failure("missed_call");
    }



    if (!t_relay()) {
        send_reply("500","Internal Error");
    };
    exit;
}




branch_route[per_branch_ops] {
    xlog("new branch at $ru\n");
}


onreply_route[handle_nat] {

    xlog("incoming reply\n");
}


failure_route[missed_call] {
    if (t_was_cancelled()) {
        exit;
    }

    # uncomment the following lines if you want to block client 
    # redirect based on 3xx replies.
    ##if (t_check_status("3[0-9][0-9]")) {
    ##t_reply("404","Not found");
    ##  exit;
    ##}


}
```

I don't know if I have to replace my opensips.cfg file with opensips_residential.cfg. I have tried that and when I attempt to start my server with command 'opensipsctl start' I get several errors, I can provide them in another message if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If using `opensipsctl start`, look for the `# STARTOPTIONS=` variable in `/usr/local/opensips/etc/opensipsctlrc`, and define it as:

```
STARTOPTIONS="-f /path/to/opensips_residential.cfg"
```

When installing OpenSIPS from packages, note that the initscript's config file path becomes `/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg`, and you will have to edit/replace this file for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your certs path setup properly, I also wouldn't use a self-signed cert. Go to letsencrypt get a cert and put the path on your opensips.cfg file. Replace your existing config with the new generated configuration.